# Paste a column in a table

Tags: cut-copy-paste, formatting, os-clipboard

Suppose I have this file open in Vim:

```
AXXK  M(X)
1.1   1
1.2   8
```

And that the clipboard holds

```
U(1X)
MX1
MX2
```

**How can I easily paste that content as a new column?** I want:

```
AXXK  M(X)  U(1X)
1.1   1     MX1
1.2   8     MX2
```

I have a strong feeling I could do it very easily in the past, so maybe there is an option to enable it?

I have tried simply pasting with the cursor on the `)` character, but I get

```
AXXK  M(X)
U(1X)
MX1
MX2
1.1   1
1.2   8
```

Also the same result with `:set virtualedit=all`.

PS: The number of spaces of separation between the columns does not matter, I can filter it through `column -t` to get a pretty format if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the clipboard. For its internal registers, Vim keeps track of what type they are (`characterwise`, `linewise` or `blockwise`). See also [:h getregtype()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#getregtype%28%29).

However for the clipboard, Vim cannot know, because any program could have put data in there, so it will always assume `linewise`. You can however force a different way, just call [setreg()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#setreg%28%29) like this:

```
call setreg('+', @+, 'b')
```

This set's the content of the clipboard (the `+` register) to itself but changes the type to blockwise (the `b`).

If you need this more often, you can make use of Ingo Karkats [UnconditionalPaste plugin](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-UnconditionalPaste), that would let you paste using e.g. `+gbp` (if I am not mistaken).